# How can I prevent this breadcrumb from moving long text to a new line

Tags: css, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a breadcrumb, but if the current page title is too long, it will show it on a new line, and not break it up.. You can see an example below:

Just to clear things up, I want the text to be broken up, so it doesn't show it on a new line, but show the text right next to Blog -> and then the text that fits until it needs to break to a new line, if you get me.. Thanks

[image]

This is the code I have right now:

```css
main .breadcrumb .inner .wi-breadcrumb {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

main .breadcrumb .inner .wi-breadcrumb li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

main .breadcrumb .inner .wi-breadcrumb span {
  font-size: 10px;
}

main .breadcrumb .inner .wi-breadcrumb li a {
  color: #000;
}

main .breadcrumb .inner .wi-breadcrumb .active {
  color: #464646;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wi-breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="https://domain.dk">Forside</a></li>
  <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
  <li><a href="https://domain.dk/blog">Blog</a></li>
  <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
  <li class="active">Første blog indlæg hvor titlen er for lang til at passe</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<span>` as a child of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the active element to `display: inline;`.

```css
.wi-breadcrumb .active {
  color: #464646;
  display: inline; /* <-- This bit */
}

.wi-breadcrumb {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;

}

.wi-breadcrumb li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.wi-breadcrumb span {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.inner .wi-breadcrumb li a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wi-breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="https://domain.dk">Forside</a></li>
  <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
  <li><a href="https://domain.dk/blog">Blog</a></li>
  <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
  <li class="active">Første blog indlæg hvor titlen er for lang til at passe Første blog indlæg hvor titlen er for lang til at passe Første blog indlæg hvor titlen er for lang til at passe</li>
</ul>
```

To fix the invalid HTML you could move the chevron to the non-active li elements pretty easily (or, better, use the css `:after` pseudo element).

```
<li>
    <a href="https://domain.dk/blog">Blog</a>
    <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Typical, it's always something simple. Thanks though.